# Extending a EF Entity for business logic throws a mapping exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a model in our Database `ImportError`. I have a class the extends this model, `AssessmentImportError`. `AssessmentImportError` does not map to a table. It has a `[NotMapped]` attribute on it. When I try to select or insert a `ImportError` (not an `AssessmentImportError`...) I get the following exception:

Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in EntityFramework.MappingAPI.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Type 'DAL.SharedModels.AssessmentImportError' is not found in context 'DAL.HTTrans.Model.HTTransDB'

The models:

```
[NotMapped]
public class AssessmentImportError : ImportError
{
    public string APN { get; set; }
}

public partial class ImportError : Frameworks.Interfaces.IImportError
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ErrorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Index("IX_TableName_RecordId", 1)] 
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    // ... deleted code
```

}

Bulk Insert:

```
    private static void SaveErrors(List<IImportError> errors, int batchID)
    {
        // Casting from IImportError to ImportError. They are already an ImportError though.
        List<ImportError> castedErrors = errors.Select(e => (ImportError)e).ToList();
        using (var db = new HTTransDB())
        {
            foreach (var e in castedErrors)
            {
                e.BatchId = batchID;
            }

            db.BulkInsert(castedErrors);
            errors.Clear();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

If I change `db.BulkInsert(castedErrors)` to `db.ImportErrors.AddRange(castedErors)` I no longer have an issue. This appears to be a bug within the BulkInsert Nuget package's Mapping API.

Comment: show your select/insert please

Comment: Just to get a picture: what happens if you *only* put `[NotMapped]` on `APN`? (I know it's totally different).

Answer (score 0):

This cast:

```
errors.Select(e => (ImportError)e)
```

will still return a list of **AssessmentImportError** which are not mapped to the DB model.

What you should do is maybe an extension method (or a service) which maps from **AssessmentImportError** to the desired **ImportError** like this:

```
List<ImportError> castedErrors = errors.Select(e => e.To<ImportError>()).ToList();
```

where

> To< ImportError >() ===> returns new ImportError object

is the extension method.

Comment: In this scenario I'm never instantiating or using an `AssessmentImportError`. I'm only using `ImportError`

Comment: Are you sure that the parameter "List<IImportError> errors" is not a list of AssesmentImportError?

Comment: 100% sure. I'm updating the question with some new info.

Comment: I'm assuming you really need to use EF BulkInsert library, right?

Comment: Yes, its very possible for us to have a large number of errors. I have a workaround though. I have AssessmentImportError not extend ImportError, and have a binding function when I need to use it. The BulkInsert package doesn't notice it then.

Comment: Do you really need another class that inherits ImportError? Or can a class that does not inherit ImportError be useful? Indeed, I think there is some bugs with BulkInsert library on this one.

Comment: It would be nice to have the inheritance here if I every want to select using linq to entities, but I'm able to get databinding using raw sql so right now it's fine.